# PHP Directory Structure and Access

Tags: php

I've been reading all morning and testing but I am still trying to wrap my head around this since moving items outside of webroot.  Needless to say things are still broken.

Everything is located in var/

My scenario/problem:  Both index.php files require slide.php (located in var/libs/inc) since one of the index pages is another level down.  I have been using the below:

var/www/html/index.php  - require_once('../../libs/inc/slide.php');

var/www/html/acc/index.php  - require_once('../../../libs/inc/slide.php');

However, slide.php also harnesses connection.php which is two levels up from slide.php and then back down another directory called "connect".  I have been using the below which works for one of the above index.php files.

var/libs/inc/slide.php  - require_once('../../connect/connection.php');

var/connect/connection.php

The problem is within the html directory the sub directory of "acc" and its pages can access slide.php given the above but cannot get connection.php

How do I can I achieve this?
Current Structure:

var/www/html/index.php  - require_once('../../libs/inc/slide.php');

var/www/html/acc/index.php  - require_once('../../../libs/inc/slide.php');

var/libs/inc/slide.php  - require_once('../../connect/connection.php');

var/connect/connection.php

Comment: typically you would either just use the full path `/var/libs` with each include so the path of the including file doesn't matter or you would add `/var/libs` to the include path using [set_include_path](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) which would allow you to just specify `inc/slide.php`...etc.

Comment: Another common practice is to create a constant somewhere in a config file that gets included everywhere with the path to your lib `define('LIB_PATH','/var/libs/')` and then including using that `include(LIB_PATH.'inc/slide.php')`. This is nice because if the path ever changes you only have to change the constant.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I will try your second suggestion.  That sounds more delightful.  I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There are three common practices.

1. You just specify the absolute path `/var/libs/` with each include so it points to the files regardless of where you are including. For example: `/var/libs/inc/slide.php`
2. You can add the lib path to the list of places php will look for a file when including using [set_include_path](http://www.php.net/set_include_path). This would allow you to just specify `inc/slide.php` to include a file.
3. You use the absolute path but define the first part in a constant like `define('LIB_PATH', 'var/libs/')`. Put that in a config file that gets included everywhere and then you use that when including like: `include(LIB_PATH.'inc/slide.php')`.

Number 1 is probably the fastest but is a little dirty. It's nice if you are just prototyping and need to get it done quick to test something. Number 2 works, but I personally don't like it (I personally don't like changing configuration variables at runtime, but that is me). Number 3 is the most common among most libraries. Also constants defined in the global scope are available in all scopes so they can be used inside functions and classes without having to call `global` like a variable.

Comment: Jonathan, so I chose number 3.  I am including it in certain files where need be, but now I am getting "Notice: Constant LIB already defined in /var/pathToConfigFile where defining it.  It's odd though because I dont get it on the root index page, but when sent to the sub index I receive this Notice.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are likely including the config file in more than one script. So like if A.php includes the config and you also include B.php that also includes the config. You can change include to `include_once()` and the config script will only be included the first time called or check if the variable is defined before defining it which a quick short hand is `defined('LIB')||define('LIB','value');`. The define part will only run if defined is false.

Comment: hahahaahaha. yeah I found it.  I was.  ugh.  I set them both to include_once